# Calling C++ RPC services with the GWT

Tags: c++, gwt

what is the best way to implement C++ functionality in Java?
Currently I call a RPC service which, throw JNI calls the C++ function and returns the result to the client. Since this methode produces a big overhead, I wanted to know if somebody had a simimlar problem and how he solved it?

Regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [JNA](http://jna.java.net/) or [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)

Comment: ok, that was what I was going to use. I was just afraid I'm missing a better solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using GWT on client side. You can use JSON to call  C++ services..